# How To Install The NOOK SDK 1.2 Android Add-On

Tags: android, nook

I am using Eclipse IDE for Android deve & trying to install Nook SDK  1.2 Android Add-On.
I referring   to this link - https://nookdeveloper.barnesandnoble.com/tools-services/sdk.html

But when I try to add the available package I am getting this message

Failed to fetch URL http://su.barnesandnoble.com/nook/sdk/addon.xml/repository.xml, reason: File not found
XML verification failed for http://su.barnesandnoble.com/nook/sdk/addon.xml.
Error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'sdk:sdk-addon'.

and it shows Validate XML on the top and the process gets stuck at that point

What to do ? please help !

Answer (score 2):

The url for downloading **Nook SDK 1.2 Android Add-On** has changed.

Try new one:
http://su.barnesandnoble.com/nook/sdk/addon.xml

I suggest to remove old URLs to outdated B&N repositories. Using updated URL you can download new addon version - **Barnes and Noble, Inc., Android API 8, revision 1**  (currently)

Additionally, you can register developer account on http://nookdeveloper.barnesandnoble.com/ and keep your eye on consequence changes.